# Please- Chinese Chop/Stamp translation

Tags: translation, seal

I purchased this lovely carved horse chop today but I can not read the characters… is anyone with that skill willing to help me translate please? [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a seal, so you have to flip the image horizontally

[image]

From left to right, top to bottom, it read: 維廉波拿特. Seems like an old transliteration of the English name "William Porter"

The modern Mandarin transliteration of  "William Porter" is "威廉波特"

Judging from the crude penmanship, it is not from a famous, or even skilled artisan

Comment: 波拿特 seems like it could also match the surname “Polat“.